# angular-google-charts not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tried simple angular + angular-google-charts, but it's not working at all. No chart is displayed. Test code follows:

```
//bower.json
{
        "dependencies": {
                "jquery": "2.1.3",
                "angular": "1.2.9",
                "angular-ui-select": "0.9.9",
                "select2": "3.5.2",
                "bootstrap": "3.3.2",
                "rxjs": "2.3",
                "angular-google-chart": "0.0.11"
        },
        "resolutions": {
                "angular": ">=1.2.18"
        }
}
```

And test html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/select2/select2.css"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/select2/select2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/rxjs/dist/rx.all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-google-chart/ng-google-chart.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-google-chart/sample.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-google-chart/partials/annotation.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-google-chart/partials/generic.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-google-chart/partials/fat.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
            var app = angular.module('test', []);
            app.controller('TestController', function($scope) {
                $scope.text = 'Hello';
                $scope.chartObject = {};
                $scope.onions = [
                {v: "Onions"},
                {v: 3},
                ];

                $scope.chartObject.data = {"cols": [
                {id: "t", label: "Topping", type: "string"},
                {id: "s", label: "Slices", type: "number"}
                ], "rows": [
                {c: [
                    {v: "Mushrooms"},
                    {v: 3},
                    ]},
                    {c: $scope.onions},
                    {c: [
                        {v: "Olives"},
                        {v: 31}
                        ]},
                        {c: [
                            {v: "Zucchini"},
                            {v: 1},
                            ]},
                            {c: [
                                {v: "Pepperoni"},
                                {v: 2},
                                ]}
                                ]};
                            });
        }());
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="test">
    <div ng-controller="TestController">
        <div>{{text}}</div>
        <div google-chart chart="chartObject" style="{{cssStyle}}"></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Code taken from http://bouil.github.io/angular-google-chart/#/fat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not including the googlechart module in your app's dependencies - try:

```
var app = angular.module('test', ['googlechart']);
```